# Working with htaccess files on Windows - actually save file as .htaccess?

Tags: windows, .htaccess, filenames

When working with htaccess files on Windows, is it possible to save the file as `.htaccess` ? (Rather than having to rename on LAMP server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Windows command line or Powershell to rename a file, or you could simply go to the desired directory and make it with `notepad .htaccess`.  It'll prompt if you want to create the file, click "yes," and you're done.

Comment: Or, just use Explorer. You have to have file extensions turned on, though.

Comment: @Mike - Nope, in Vista and 7, Explorer won't let you only use ".htaccess" - it tells you that "You must type a file name."

Comment: @derekerdmann Huh. That's strange... I could have sworn that I've done this in XP... Maybe not though...

Comment: @Mike - Just checked using XP Mode, and it doesn't look like XP lets you rename to ".htaccess" either.  There might be a setting that would allow it, but I doubt it's easy to find.

Comment: Yup, I remember doing this in XP native years ago - but in Win 7 - it won't let you rename to .filename in Explorer

Answer (score 3):

Use notepad, save the file as ".htacess" using double quotes around the name to ignore illegal characters.

Comment: this is clever! but i stay away from notepad since it often messes up the file due to windows memory handling errors